# Javascript: how get all the values and id from an inputs array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function

So I'm trying to get all the values and id of every input from an array, but I have an issue, the user can duplicate the input and each input have a randomly generated ID so I can't select the data with the ID and every input use `name="cate[]"` so every input have the same name, so I can use something like this:

```
function regTour() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName('cat[]');
    var k = "The respective values are :";

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var a = input[i];
        k = k + "array[" + i + "].value= "
                           + a.value + " ";
    }
    console.log('Console: ' + k);
}
```

but how I can get the ID from every input from the array paired with the input value?

Edit: -------------------

the input looks like this:

```
    <input type="text" id="1666239497429" name="cat[]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="12983172462" name="cat[]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="812361647812" name="cat[]" class="form-control">
```

this input it's created dynamically by the user so the id changes, this id later it's stored with other sub fields that should be related with that id, that's why it's some kind important for me be able to store all the id's

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That give me the value, but I need the ID

Comment: no, that give everything

Comment: I'm new into this, that's why I'm asking and that page doesn't help too much to understand, probably if I'm more advance I can understand, but I'm more an example learner

Comment: while you didn't [ask your question correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding at least the HTML code to it with this JS code, there is little chance that you will find a satisfactory answer

Comment: there is no needs to use some Id on forms elements like input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id of DOM elements using the `id` property. From your example, just use `a.id` to access it.

Side note, you should use `const` instead of `var` if the variable is not going to be changed, and `let` if it does change. `var` shouldn't be used any more.

```
function regTour() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName('cat[]');
    var k = "The respective values are :";

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var a = input[i];
        k = k + "array[" + i + "].value= "
                           + a.value + " array[" + i + "].id= " + a.id;
    }
    console.log('Console: ' + k);
}
```

Comment: This code-only answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

can you share more data from the front? how is your form?

This ist OK `var input = document.getElementsByName('cat[]');` but I'm not sure what the problem is